# SVN to Web root project transfer

Tags: svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

I an using ubuntu server

- I have my web root directory at location `/var/www/html`
- I have setup svn inside it at location `/var/www/html/svn`
- I have a project in the uat directory `/var/www/html/uat`

And the project inside uat is working fine.
I am developing the site in my local.
When i commit the file it did go to the svn.
Now i want to export the committed file from svn folder to uat.

**So the flow is From my local to svn (via commit) and then svn to uat (via export or something).**

Please tell me how do i do that? 
Is there any gui tools or some command which will help me to directly export from svn to project folder?

Basically i want that when i commit from local it should reflect the live site without opening the file of live site. 
Thanx in advance.